# What is the difference between MeterUsage and BatchMeterUsage AWS Marketplace Metering Service APIs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, aws-marketplace

I have read the official document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplacemetering/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html
but I am not clear with usgae of these two APIs

Answer (score 2):

BatchMeterUsage allows you to submit up to 25 MeterUsage requests with a single API call instead of requiring the user the invoke the API many times.

AWS provides "Batch" requests for many many other services and they all typically behave in the same way: they allow you to submit many requests via a single API call to reduce traffic and improve performance.

Batch requests contain an a list of request objects instead of just a single object.

Note: Specifically for `BatchMeterUsage`, each request must apply to the same `ProductCode`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get the use of "BatchMeterUsage" but my question expects a different answer.

Comment: ok, after re-reading, I think I understand, are you just asking what these are used for?

Comment: @JDD yes, please

Answer (score 0):

BatchMeterUsage is to be used for SaaS products and MeterUsage is for AMI and Containers products. [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplacemetering/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)
Batch is for updating the customers of your SaaS. in meterUsage there is no need to send the customer ID because it runs on the customer's account.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplacemetering/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html